# 4.2 Example (Regular surfaces in $\mathbb R^n$) of chapter $0$ of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry.  In my view, the $x$ and $y$ are differentiable homeomorphism. Thus, $x^{-1}\circ y$ and $y^{-1}\circ x$ are differentiable homeomorphism. Why the proof of this book is so complex ?  Whether I misunderstand it ?

> > [image]

> > [image]

Comment: You cannot immediately say ${\bf x}^{-1}\circ {\bf y}$ and its inverse are differentiable--you need to apply the Inverse Function Theorem to conclude this (which is what do Carmo does).

Comment: @Glare  Sorry, I am not understand you well. In my view, since $x$ and $y$ are differentiable homeomorphism. Thus, $x^{-1}$ existence and differentiable, so $x^{-1}\circ y$ is differentiable. Why it is wrong ?

Comment: You can say $x^{-1}$ exists since $x$ is a homeomorphism, but again, you cannot say $x^{-1}$ is differentiable without the inverse function theorem. A counterexample to what you describe could be the function $x: t\mapsto t^3$, which is a differentiable homeomorphism but does not have differentiable inverse, as $x^{-1}: s\mapsto s^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $s=0$.

Comment: @Glare  Thanks, I understand. For example, $y=x^3$ is differentiable, but $x=y^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $y=0$.

Comment: @Glare  Haha, I think a same example with you .